# How do I pass returnUrl to Login page in Blazor Server application?

Tags: c#, server, identity, blazor

I have a simple Blazor server application, with Identity using Individual Authentication.  I created the app from the VS 2019 standard `dotnet new` template.

In some parts of the app I would like to direct the user to the login page, while passing along a `returnUrl` parameter.  I've tried the following variations of code to pass this parameter (**counter** is the page I want to return to):

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl=counter", forceLoad: true);
```

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl='/counter'", forceLoad: true);
```

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl='./counter'", forceLoad: true);
```

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl='~/counter'", forceLoad: true);
```

However, with all of these, I get an error message that the "URI is not local".  Error message is:

> "InvalidOperationException: The supplied URL is not local. A URL with
>   an absolute path is considered local if it does not have a
>   host/authority part. URLs using virtual paths ('~/') are also local."

Can anyone suggest the proper formatting of the returnUrl parameter in this situation?  For further background, I am following suggestions from @iambacon (thanks to Colin!), in his [blog post](https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/blazor-authentication-and-authorisation-redirect-to-login) about redirecting to the login page for Blazor apps.  It's a great article and accomplishes part of what I want: redirect to login when the user is not authenticated.  I would just like to add the extra feature of returning back to that URL after the auth is complete.

Comment: Does the error occur on NavigateTo() or when you leave the Login page again?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> "URI is not local".

To solve this...

Do the following:

1. Create in the Pages folder a component named RedirectToLogin with the following code:

### RedirectToLogin.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code{
  [Parameter]
  public string ReturnUrl {get; set;}
  protected override  void OnInitialized()
  {
        ReturnUrl = "~/" + ReturnUrl;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl={ReturnUrl}", 
           forceLoad:true);
  }
}
```

Open App.razor and add the following code to AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized

```
<NotAuthorized>
@{
    var returnUrl = 
    NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
    <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@returnUrl"/>
    
 }
</NotAuthorized>
```

Also inject the NavigationManager at the top of the App component like this:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
```

To test this, at the top of the Fetchdata (or Counter if you like) component page add the @attribute directive for the Authorize attribute, like this: `@attribute [Authorize]` When an unauthenticated user tries to access the Fetchdata page, the AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized delegate property is executed, and the RedirectToLogin component is rendered with its parameter attribute set to the current url.

**Update**

The following addition is to add a login and logout buttons to your App...

1. Create a component named LoginDisplay.razor in the Shared folder, and add the following code into it:

```
     <AuthorizeView>
      <Authorized>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, 
        @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log 
        out</button>
        </form>
      </Authorized>
         <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
         </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
```

In the MainLayout component add the LoginDisplay element as follows:

```
<div class="top-row px-4 auth">
    <LoginDisplay />
    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" 
         target="_blank">About</a>
</div>
```

Run your app and test the login and logout button...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I had planned a similar design.  I implemented all your code, and I am now getting the same error.  At a breakpoint in the Login.cshtml.cs code, I can see the returnUrl is set to 'fetchData'.  I don't understand why it thinks this is a non-local path.

Comment: Update: I found that if I click on the fetchData link in the app, I get the 'URI is not local' error.  But if I instead edit the url to /fetchData path, then I get a different error.  The breakpoint is inside the RedirectToLogin component, at the .NavigateTo method.  Error message is "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.dll" with no more details.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  You're saying the url is not local, but you're also saying it works doing it this way.  Why does your solution work if the returnUrl ("fetchData") is not local?

Comment: To reproduce: dotnet new blazor --auth Individual.  Add @attribute [Authorize] to /fetchdata page, and add the code you recommended to App.razor.  I did no other changes to the default VS 2019 template.  Run the app, register an account, go to Home, click on FetchData, log in, you will see the "URL is not local error."

Comment: Just to further clarify:  The navigation to /Identity/Account/Login is working.  I agree this is not a local url, it is outside the SPA, but this is not causing any error.  It is a simple navigation and is working.  It is the subsequent navigation (after entering login credentials) to the returnUrl ("fetchdata") that is failing with the "URL is not Local" error.  This failure at this point, with this url, does not make sense to me.

Comment: "after entering login credentials" This is the key information which you've failed to provide...

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and updates.  The basic case is working now, but the other (important) case is still not working.  If you go to the Home page and edit url to /fetchdata, you get an exception in the RedirectToLogin component.  I need users to be able to navigate directly to a spa page (from link in e-mail, etc.).  Maybe this error is ok, because if you continue debugging (ignore exception), all seems to work.

Comment: @Randy Gamage, I'll try to solve this issue, but it can only be done tomorrow. Please, delete your comments above so that we won't be moved to the chat...

Comment: @Randy Gamage, sorry, but I do not understand what you mean here: If you go to the Home page and edit url to /fetchdata, you get an exception in the RedirectToLogin component. However, I've added new functionality code in my answer, under the Update title...

Comment: This solution does apply also for Blazor WebAssembly :)