# How can I redirect to another page when a form is submitted after being checked using Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am currently developing a log in and sign up page using Blazor Server. After the fields are submitted in my form, is there a way to redirect to another .razor page? I am calling a submitFields function to verify the log in information via an "@onclick" event handler for this specific example. In the submitFields function, I have tried to use Navigation Manager but it does not do anything. Further more, I tried re-initializing the page with the check being set to true so I can redirect but I am also having trouble with this approach as well. Any ideas? Below is my source code.

```
@code {
    private string email;
    private string password;
    private bool check = false;
    private string mySetting = "";

    // form input logic
    private void submitFields()
    {
        User person = new User();
        person.connect = mySetting;
        person.email = email;
        person.password = password;
        //when decrypting use Encrypt.hashString(password)
        person.logIn();
        check = person.check;
        // I want to redirect to another page here
        /*
        if(check == true)
        {
            yay youre logged in, lets go to a new page!
        } else
        {
            dont go anywhere
        }
        */
    }

    // on load -> call this func
    private void initMethod()
    {
        mySetting = _config.GetValue<string>("MySetting"); //on load get hidden connection string from appsettings.json
    }

    // on load
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        initMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728006/how-do-i-pass-returnurl-to-login-page-in-blazor-server-application

Comment: After submitting the form, Firefox ask if I want to save the password. and no redirect is performed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to inject NavigationManager. Then you can use it to navigate to another page. Example:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code {
    private void submitFields()
    {
        User person = new User();
        person.connect = mySetting;
        person.email = email;
        person.password = password;
        //when decrypting use Encrypt.hashString(password)
        person.logIn();
        check = person.check;
        // I want to redirect to another page here

        if(check == true)
        {

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/account/dashboard");

        } else
        {
            dont go anywhere
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Also turns out that part of the problem was that my function wasn't being called in my form correctly.